# Como fazer Join com Sum e Group By

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

Eu estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa em SQL utilizando Join entre duas tabelas. A primeira tabela é uma tabela que contém valores de economias mensais para um determinado projeto. Cada vez que alguém cadastra um projeto no site, uma rotina PHP gera 12 valores, um no mês corrente e mais 11 meses para frente. Como o website tem uma funcionalidade de o gerente da fábrica poder escolher o período que deseja mostrar as economias, eu criei uma tabela contendo somente os meses no período que o gerente deseja visualizar. Eu gostaria de criar uma pesquisa SQL que baseada na tabela calendário, servisse de base para a tabela contendo as economias e datas reais das ações implementadas.

Em outras palavras, para cada mês da tabela calendário, eu gostaria de obter a soma da tabela de ações do respectivo mês (somar todas as ações naquele mês da tabela de ações) da coluna Saving_Mensal e retornar todos os meses do intervalo definido na tabela calendário. Nos meses da tabela calendário que não existir savings, gostaria que retornasse o valor 0.

A tabela calendario tem a seguinte estrutura
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A tabela com os 12 valores das ações tem a seguinte estrutura
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pesquisa que estou tentando executar é: `SELECT date_format(calendar.Data, '%Y-%m') as Mes, sum(action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal) AS Saving FROM calendar LEFT JOIN action_plan_detail ON action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal = calendar.Saving_Mensal GROUP BY Mes`

e o retorno é nulo em todos os meses
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me auxiliar a determinar qual a pesquisa correta a ser feita aqui?

O resultado que eu gostaria no final seria

```
Mes     | Saving_Mensal
--------|--------------
01-2018 | 20000
02-2018 | 20000
03-2018 | 20000
04-2018 | 20000
05-2018 | 20000
06-2018 | 0      * não existe nenhum lançamento na tabela de açoes com valores neste mês
07-2018 | 0
08-2018 | 0
09-2018 | 20000
10-2018 | 20000
11-2018 | 20000
12-2018 | 20000
```

Comment: Entendi nada, recomendo tentar simplificar sua pergunta e focar mais no problema, não no contexto.

Comment: Para cada mês existente na tabela calendário, somar todos os meses equivalentes na tabela de ações (somar Saving_Mensal para todos os registros com mês equivalente da tabela calendário) e retornar o valor total de Saving_Mensal naquele mês, para todos os meses existentes na tabela calendário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fernando, acredito que o join deva ser feito na campo calendar.Data e não no action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal.

```
SELECT date_format(calendar.Data, '%Y-%m') AS Mes, 
SUM(action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal) AS Saving FROM calendar 
LEFT JOIN action_plan_detail ON calendar.Data = action_plan_detail.Data 
GROUP BY Mes
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Carlos! Fazendo o join da tabela como você falou deu certo! Só mostra os meses presentes na tabela calendário... no entanto os valores não migraram ou não foram somados... retornaram todos como zero.

Comment: Ok Fernando. As datas são sempre do primeiro dia do mês: 01/01/18, 01/02/18 ... 01/12/2018? Se não, podes substituir a comparação direta do campo data por LEFT JOIN YEAR(calendar.Data) = YEAR(action_plan_detail.Data ) AND MONTH(calendar.Data) = MONTH(action_plan_detail.Data)

Comment: Não, as datas podem variar de dia, porém seja dia 01 ou dia 15, considera todo o mês.

Comment: Testa assim: `SELECT date_format(calendar.Data, '%Y-%m') AS Mes, 
SUM(action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal) AS Saving FROM calendar LEFT JOIN YEAR(calendar.Data) = YEAR(action_plan_detail.Data ) AND MONTH(calendar.Data) = MONTH(action_plan_detail.Data) GROUP BY Mes`

Comment: Não funcionou pq o Select ta selecionando duas colunas em duas tabelas diferentes... devo selecionar tudo primeiro da tabela Calendar ou da tabela de ações?

Comment: SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(action_plan_detail.Data, '%Y-%m') AS Mes,
    SUM(action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal) AS Saving
FROM
    action_plan_detail
  LEFT JOIN
    calendar ON YEAR(action_plan_detail.Data) = YEAR(calendar.Data) AND
    MONTH(action_plan_detail.Data) = YEAR(calendar.Data)
GROUP BY Mes   --- Realizando a query assim ele retorna legal, porém os meses inexistentes na tabela ações não são retornados com valor 0...

Comment: Sim, pois sua tabela principal mudou. Ao invés de calendar, ficou action...
Qual foi o erro mesmo do select que te mandei?? Esse duas colunas em duas tabelas diferentes..

Comment: Percebi um erro na consulta que te mandei.. executa assim: `SELECT date_format(calendar.Data, '%Y-%m') AS Mes, SUM(action_plan_detail.Saving_Mensal) AS Saving FROM calendar LEFT JOIN action_plan_detail ON YEAR(calendar.Data) = YEAR(action_plan_detail.Data ) AND MONTH(calendar.Data) = MONTH(action_plan_detail.Data) GROUP BY Mes`

Comment: Carlos! Sensacional agora funcionou, os valores que não existem retornaram nulo! Posso pedir só um último conselho: toda esta pesquisa deve ser efetuada de acordo com um terceiro campo, o setor... Por exemplo na tabela de ações tem um campo chamado "Area"... no site existe um campo onde o usuario escolhe a area para filtrar.. seria usando  o WHERE?

Comment: Legal @FernandoFerrariFernandes! Isso aí! Tenta usar _alias_ para tuas tabelas. Fica mais bacana! ;)

Comment: Você tem razão, vou fazer isso! Olha muito obrigado pelo apoio viu, você realmente me ajudou muito!